# Multirows inside multicolums not working properly

Tags: multicolumn, multirow

I'm trying to make the "Radeon HD4000" 2 rows tall and 2 columns wide, yet it either makes a giant mess or appears an error. I've tried:

```
\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{2008}} & GeForce 9 & \multicolumn{2}{|c|} 
{\multirow{2}{*}{Radeon HD4000}}  \\ 
\cline{2-2} & GeForce 200 \\ \hline
```

and to put a multicolumn inside the multirow.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us code in form of complete small document with your table. Code should be copied from LaTeX editor, not image of it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code snippet has error: missed is ampersand in the second code sniped. Correct is:

```
    \hline
\multirow{2.4}{*}{\textbf{2008}} 
    & GeForce 9     & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\multirow{2.4}{*}{Radeon HD4000}}  \\
    \cline{2-2} 
    & GeForce 200   & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{ }                               \\ 
    \hline
```

Note, in each table row must contain all ampersands even there is no content in its last cells.

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much

Comment: @PedroMendes, you can accept my answer (by clicking on check mark at top left side of answer)!